# Infer object key type from sibling key's value

Tags: typescript

I have an Object Type `Options` with two keys:

1. `strategy`: a function that requires one parameter of unknown type
2. `parameter`: same type as `strategy`'s first argument

I want to be able to do the following

```
type FooParameter = { foo: string }
type BarParameter = { bar: string }

const fooOptions: Options = {
  strategy: (parameter: FooParameter) => {},
  parameter: { foo: 'foo' }
}
const barOptions: Options = {
  strategy: (parameter: BarParameter) => {},
  parameter: { bar: 'bar' }
}
```

The type `fooOptions.parameter` should be inferred from `fooOptions.strategy` and `barOptions.parameter` from `barOptions.strategy`

Is that possible with TypeScript today?

Comment: Instead of inferring, why not make `Options` generic? E.g. `type Options<T> = { strategy: (parameter: T) => void, parameter: T }`.

Comment: I should have added, I tried that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgAoEMBOOAthMBHgHxQC8UA3gFBRRrAGkDmIAXFABRj4iJMj1wFipPAEpqlAG5IEAEwA0jKAPHC8owRLL0AvgG569UJCgAxJEjFDJ1OlABmtnizwIU7Q+fDQAEL49vp4TrRQAEb4Hqze7FB+9ADGqCyutnCI6TzZyOgR6p44HNx8mg4i1rah2jJUlLSGakyVYTyRbkg8AOTdvUlGqenA0fj5ubDwBWhFTCVlPPx62jzBeHWSDU0t6u1rzjE6UL3Hg36GQA 

But I'd like to avoid the need to pass a parameter type

Comment: The context is the `authStrategy` and `auth` options for https://github.com/octokit/core.js#authentication. `authStrategy` is set to an external package, the parameter type is unknown. So inferring it would be a much better developer experience than using a type parameter.

Comment: Typescript can infer the type parameters of generic types, so the caller doesn't need to explicitly write that type. I should have been clearer that this is instead of your library inferring it, not instead of the user having their data type inferred. The sample usage in your docs looks like it should work fine with a generic type, without any changes to the sample usage code.

Comment: "Typescript can infer the type parameters of generic types" that sounds like what I want, but couldn't figure out how. Could you share an example in an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine to do this is using a generic type. I think it's unlikely there is a solution where the compiler will check that `parameter` is a suitable argument for `strategy` without using a generic type.

```js
type Options<T> = {
    strategy: (parameter: T) => void,
    parameter: T
}
```

This means that if `Options` is used in a type annotation then you have to provide a type parameter:

```js
const fooOptions: Options<FooParameter> = {
    strategy: (parameter: FooParameter) => {},
    parameter: { foo: 'foo' }
}

function useOptions<T>(o: Options<T>): void {
    o.strategy(o.parameter);
}
```

However, anywhere you allow the compiler to infer the type (i.e. whenever you don't use a type annotation), it is not necessary to provide an explicit type for the generic type parameter. In particular, users of an API such as the `useOptions` function can pass an object literal, and enjoy the benefits of type-checking and type inference:

```js
useOptions({
    strategy: param => {
        let x = param.x; // Inferred as number
        let y = param.y; // Inferred as string

        // Error: Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ x: number, y: string }'
        let z = param.z;
    },
    parameter: { x: 1, y: 'foo' }
});
```

Note that the user in this example doesn't have to explicitly write `{ x: number, y: string }` or an equivalent type in order to use the API.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgCoD4oF4oBvAKCnKjWACcBDYCAcxAC4oAKMWugWwgepssASgJ4AbkgQATADRkKXXvwiCoWEgF8SJUJCgAxJEgAK3WnwEFiUAGbG2VaghSMo2vdABC3M8quERFAARtyONC5u2iQAxqhUdsZwiPFsycjoGEam5paqeIEK5E70TKwcShYqatl+VQKi+HhEmvIUUJV5akH2SGwA5L397lqx8cAh3OmpsPAZmD7UdV0FxEWUNKXMbJy51WyLy9WNza3rnfs2oWr918Pa0bYArigxKShQT2gQ05m47H1Zu9MLhhGxJDI1u0kAA6EoMZgAmEXBoAblGJC+Pzm8XYpHa8LKbE6Yih7QoABt+FAAB7WTowmmoqAAehZUAAkihbKpqBBpFBaGgoCgnjxgqp1u0qRMQPTcjCQMy2Zzubz+YLhU5IjpyRQVQBRajUJBqMAmyDUUBQfoAL2G0iQEGFKCQEwgNIQCVQUE8NqCNLYovFqlkUHK2tc7n6Usp1Nt8t4MNt6PaZ3aKNUbADbAAjGHyoNjPctMJ0UA)

Comment: In the `useOptions` example, it seems that the type of the `param` method argument is inferred from the `parameter`. I'm looking for the opposite. Any ideas?

Comment: Either will be inferred from the other. If you call it with `strategy: (param: FooParameter) => {}` then it will check that `parameter` is of type `FooParameter`.